# Cannot remove index.php from CodeIgniter URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My directory structure is /var/www/CI/ with all the folders viz., application, system under the folder CI.  Have created a .htaccess file under CI.

Following is the code in .htacess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Still localhost/CI/blog gives 404 error.  Can anyone guide as to where this rule is wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please try the following

At first, make sure you set the config file like the following..

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also make sure that **mod_rewrite** is enabled in the httpd.conf file and after that, overwrite your .htaccess file which is located your project root folder not in the application folder with the following code..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: I have been threw several blogs and post looking for this answer and you are the only one who had the correct answer for me as well as made it very clear on what to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @Travis Michael Heller

Comment: I forgot to add $config['index_page'] = ' ';

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the "project root folder".  I have struggled with figuring out where this .htaccess file should go.  It's not like there is only one.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure in your `application/config/config.php` file this is set as follows:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also do this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^CI/(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^CI/(.*)$ CI/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Typically you don't put CI in its own directory and put `application` and `system` in the root folder.

Comment: Did the above but still not working.  Is there some other place also that needs to be configured?

Answer (score 3):

Check your Apache configuration so that it is allowing an override.
If the `AllowOverride` is set to `None`, the rewrite won't work for you.

Adding the following to your `httpd.conf` (NOT your .htaccess) should fix your problem

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't it be httpd.conf ?  Also my httpd.conf file is empty.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... it's httpd.conf! I fixed my answer. I hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following steps,
1. Create .htaccess file in the document root [`myroot_folder/.htaccess`]. 
2. open the config file in `application/config/config.php` and do the following

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

remove `index.php` from your base url
if it is `$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/myroot_folder/index.php';`
change it to `$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/myroot_folder/';`

Now open the `.htaccess` file and add the following code block

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works. Although, please make sure your **mod_rewrite** is enabled,

1. Find the `httpd.conf` file under the `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf` folder inside the Apache’s installation folder.
2. Find the following line `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in the `httpd.conf` file.You can do this easily by searching the keyword “mod_rewrite”.
3. Remove the `#` at the starting of the line, `#` represents that line is commented.
4. Then **restart the apache server**.
5. You can see now `mod_rewrite` in the Loaded Module section while doing `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make `.htaccess` file and put this code.

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2) Change:

```
 $config['index_page'] = ''; 
 remove index.php present in config.php file
```

3) Rewrite on from your server

Answer (score -1):

**If you have not worked all but that you did so, try this:**

Change **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All** in the virtual host file in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

[Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549808/4043476)