# CodeIgniter | .htaccess removing index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

ok, i did exactly as asked in the documentation of codeigniter, created new file .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

i am using xampp, so my url for accessing the site was

```
http://localhost:12/projects/zorkif_nextgen/index.php/main
```

now after applying the above .htaccess file, i tried it without index.php like this

```
http://localhost:12/projects/zorkif_nextgen/main
```

but instead of working, it is redirecting me to this url

```
http://localhost:12/xampp
```

How to resolve this issue?

plus i am getting error on my page after trying the .htaccess

on top of page message is appearing,

```
 Error Occured.
Warning!. Make sure you perform the correct action.
The Action has been completed Successfully.
```

---

Edit:

Here is some of my config.php file settings

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'zk_ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sys_ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Exact and complete answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297770/cannot-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url

Comment: Instead of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` in your root folder/.htaccess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try defining the RewriteBase to /projects/zorkif_nextgen

```
RewriteBase /projects/zorkif_nextgen
```

Comment: very nice. Thank you. Yes, it is working now just as i wanted :)

Answer (score 15):

this is works well for me:

1- create .htaccess file in the root folder with the following content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2- from the config file change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply, i tried your code,
It works but it is same, i have to write the index.php to make it work.
if i try zorkif_nextgen/main then it again redirects me to the localhost:12/xampp??

why its redirecting me to the main root.?

Comment: I've tried 10 of these. you're is the one that worked for my xampp.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt) 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

For future reading This will help you [Codeigniter remove index php from url using htaccess](http://agungmulyawan.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-url-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

You may have look at config/routes.php.

It may have been set to a default controller.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use an .htaccess file to remove index.php from your URLs.  This is an issue in your config.  Look specifically at `$config['base_url']` and `$config['index_page']`

Comment: Can you tell how i can remove index.php from url without htaccess?