# CodeIgniter Access controller without index.php in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to remove index.php from url while accessing controller.
This is the current working url : `http://localhost/jplugins/index.php/home/index/`
But it gives error(404 Page Not Found) when i access using url : `http://localhost/jplugins/home/index/`

Here are the things i tried while searching over stackoverflow :

 1. set `$config['index_page'] = "";` in config/config.php

 2. place .htaccess , I have tried every htaccess file i found in threads.. none work

 3. enable rewrite module in xampp

 4. set `$config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost/jplugins/';` didnt work either

 5. Reinstall Xampp. No change

 6. change `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` . I have tried every method listed in comment but it only gives home/index output no matter what the query is, like `http://localhost/jplugins/asdwhadsadasdasdasdadas/asdasda//asdad` --> will give same output as `http://localhost/jplugins/index.php/home/index/`. 

Lastly i sent my whole code to someone who was also using xampp. It worked there perfectly. Using same xampp version 3.2.1( May 7th 2013).
 I'm using windows 7 32bit.

 What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you setup the proper allow / deny directives to use .htaccess on your apache virtual host?

Comment: do you need to set that? the other person tried my code on stock xampp settings.

Comment: Depends, maybe try comparing the vhost files for both configurations to see if there are any differences so you can eliminate that as the culprit.

Comment: Does the solution in this question work for you? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350137/codeigniter-htaccess-removing-index-php-from-url?rq=1

Comment: after adding line RewriteBase /jsplugins . output is still the same. redirected to xampp page with the htaccess from the answer below

Comment: It seems you have another .htaccess file (parent) which redirects you `localhost/xampp/splash.php` when a file not found.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.htaccess` file in your `jplugins` directory and add the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: with your htaccess. when i open http://localhost/jplugins/home it redirects to http://localhost/xampp/splash.php

Comment: Very weird... And if you run your code with another program, like [USB Webserver](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/)? The problem can be you're not running the code in the root.

Comment: And nothing else is in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: In CodeIgniter, have you set a default controller?

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'home'; and 
$route['assets/(:any)'] = 'assets/$1';   in routes.php located in config

Comment: Than I must apologize, I can't help you further then this.

Comment: i dont get it. all the data when transfered to another pc (win 8 64 bit) works perfectly with same xampp and same xampp settings. What could be the problem? only difference is that im using win7 32bit. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Maybe a browser problem -> reset history and cache?

Comment: nope.. tried on IE and also on that win 8 browser through lan. same output. Anyways Thanks for help.