# Error while running codeigniter php project

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in php project using codeigniter. I am very new to codeigniter. I have exiting project that i managed to run properly.But when i am inserting username and password,its 
giving me error as=

```
 "The requested URL /PRS/index.php/login was not found on this server."
```

I am using wamp server. httpd.conf file has documentRoot as  "c:/wamp/www/PRS/"
My .htaccess file has code as-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /PRS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PRS/index.php/$1 [L]
```

My project's config.php file has code as-

```
$BASE_URL = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/PRS/"  ; 
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_USER = "root";
$DB_PASSWORD = "mysql";
$DB_NAME = "prsdb";
```

So can someone please help me..

Comment: Could you add info on what URL you're accessing to get that error, and where under the server root your application is placed? `/PRS` does not seem to be obviously connected to `/wishlist` in any way.

Comment: Ya i edited my code as above..i am using url as-http://www.prs.net/PRS/index.php/login..My application is placed in wamp/www/PRS

Comment: Looks like you've set it up to rewrite without the index.php and the PRS directory. Try taking those two out of your URL. So wamp/www/login

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled in httpd.conf file and after that, overwrite your .htaccess file which is located your project root folder with the following code..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

And then set your base url like following..

```
$BASE_URL = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/PRS/";
```

And change your config file like following..

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And finally use the following url to access..

```
prs.net/PRS/login
```

Or, you can check the following url to get some help..

[Cannot remove index.php from CodeIgniter URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297770/cannot-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url/14301819#14301819)