# In Codeigniter, how to make controller run index() without having to write /index in url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, config

I'm setting up my first personal codeigniter project and my .htaccess file is this:

```
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # Turn on URL rewriting
            RewriteEngine On

            # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
            # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
            # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
            # let it as it is
            RewriteBase /madrigal/

            # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
            RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

            # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

            # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
            RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

            # No rewriting
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

            # Rewrite to index.php/URL
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
            </IfModule>
```

I have set up my config.php file to $config['index_page'] = ''; and $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; but when I go to my controller /admin/, index isn't ran unless I type out "/index" at the end of the URL. Is my htaccess file disallowing that?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following link...

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

or,

[Cannot remove index.php from CodeIgniter URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297770/cannot-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url/)

Comment: Thank you, but the CI user guide on this is actually outdated, which is why I'm here asking.

Comment: please take a look at the second link in my answer. This is the way i do with my codeigniter app.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove this index.php by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|img|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file. You can read the documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

`$config['index_page']` is the configuration for your default page to call and not for removing index.php in your URI