# CodeIgniter remove index.php from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, configuration

I'm having some trouble removing index.php from my CI app urls. Followed the official documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/urls.html) but apparently something's missing yet.
I setup a CI app and placed it on /var/www/test on my server, where test is a symlink pointing to /home/user/websites/test.
Everything is working fine if I do `http://myIp/test/index.php/welcome`, but working if I do `http://myIp/test/welcome`.
I included an .htaccess in my test folder, containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and also played with RewriteBase property without success.
What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Have you get mod_rewrite running on the server ? `phpinfo()` will tell you if its enabled

Comment: you can check the following url...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297770/cannot-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url/14301819#14301819

Answer (score 1):

put the following in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

put this file near to index.php out of application and system  folders and near to them 
don't forget to write $config['index_page'] = ''; instead of $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Answer (score 0):

Open `application/config/config.php`, and change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I already made that too, without success.

Comment: Try removing the leading slash: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is incorrect (or faulty at best). It should be as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `[L]` flag in the `RewriteRule` indicates to apache that no further rules should be processed and that the rule should be applied immediately. See the [apache documentation about the L flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) for more information on this. In your case this is important due to the fact that you are using symlinks and `.htaccess` file instead of applying the rule to your vhost file directly, which is highly recommended given this case as well as the case that .htaccess is slow.

Comment: It doesn't work also... Am I doing something wrong? I placed my CI test app on the default Apache web folder (/var/www) through a symlink, without further configurations. I'm editing the .htaccess in the root of the test app. Something wrong here? Can this be something related to permissions somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If i have got your question right you want to make your links working & remove 'index.php' from URL.Follow following steps & let me know if that solves your issue.

1) Remove 'index.php' from config.php which is located in config directory make it look like this `$config['index_page'] = '';`

2) Add this to .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you have any doubts or issues let me know.Hope it helps.

Best Regards, Zeeshan.