# Get rid of Index.php in CodeIgniter URLs

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

How do I remove the "index.php" from my URL?

### Description

Using CI to build a simple MySQL-Php app, I cannot get rid of the "index.php" tag inside the URL:

`localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/Defult_Controller/index`

### .htaccess

`application/.htaccess` and `application/cache/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
#  slashes.
# If your page resides at
#  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
# then use
# RewriteBase /mypage/test1/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

### apache.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

### application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/";
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**PS: Im using codeIgniter 2.5.1 and xampp 3.2.1**

Comment: What happens when you go to `localhost/CodeIgniter/Defult_Controller/`? 404?

Comment: @kasun Recommend screenshot in **Description**.

Comment: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22

Comment: Please Check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297770/cannot-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url

Comment: If I am not wrong, you need to place your `.htaccess` in your root folder to remove `index.php`, `application/.htaccess` is to avoid directory view.

Comment: Thanks, The problem Solved 
My .htaccess file was in side application directory I change it to root and now its working Thank you all

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, can you accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your `.htaccess` in your root folder to remove `index.php`, `application/.htaccess` is to avoid directory view.