# Codeigniter view is available but still receive page not found error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tested my site many times but I am not able to resolve Page not found error.
well,

1 step: I create one controller and called welcomelogin.php - where I store two functions

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class WelcomeLogin extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $this->home();
}
public function home(){

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function inside(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('inside');    
}
```

2- step: In my rote.php file I simple perform follwing:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcomeLogin";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

3- step: Inside view folder I create two files one is login.php & second is inside.php with login.php contains login form and inside.php contain simple html.

Now I got login page as home page of my website which is working fine:
http://localhost/website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/

When I do following I get page not found error:
I tried with two ways and both gives me same error:

1-st way: by direct giving view name and result page not found
localhost/website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/inside

2-nd way: by giving controller name and then view but result page not found
localhost/website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/welcomelogin(controllername)/inside

Please help me as I spend almost 2 hours by searching and applying different answers and yes there are similar questions on stack and some have answer which I already tried but didn't work & those question is bit different then mine. Thanks for your time guys.:) I am running on localhost server and my apache mod_rewrite is on. thanks. & I am new to codeigniter thanks

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/


    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: what about base_url ?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url().'inside';?>">inside</a> - not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this url

```
http://localhost/website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/index.php/inside
```

hope this will work if you did not restrict the flow of `url` with `.htaccess`

Comment: Hi not working and my .htaccess file contains: Deny from all so do you think I should change anything there if yes then can you provide me the code as not so sure what could be there. thanks

Comment: @user2268488, i'm using the `htaccess` from http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/. It contains all the necessory information you need :)

Comment: Hi bro, I implement my .htaccess file with above and it seems not working as I tried by giving controller name/method name in which method name contains $this->load->view() but still not working:(

Comment: you missed the `Rewritebase` value. As per your code it will be `/website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP CI code seems fine, you should check `.htaccess` file,

As you added `.htaccess` file in question, you should add `RewriteBase` from your web directory to project home, see below sample code

```
RewriteBase /website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/
```

**Updated htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ########### TODO: deploying on subdir must rewrite this
    RewriteBase  /website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

    # you could simply throw this into an htaccess file the directory you want displayed
    Options -Indexes

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi bro can you tell me do I have to put my controller name here in .htaccess file:  # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]

Comment: So rather than welcome(/index) do I have to replace to my controller name welcomelogin in small or caps as I have class WelcomeLogin

Comment: ok, remove `### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs` section in .htaccess, ci route automatic detect it... and naming conventions could be impact on os version, you can read more here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html

Comment: Hi I update my .htaccess file can you please have a look

Comment: you should use initial htaccess file see in answer updated section

Comment: Hi bro, really thanks for your reply really appreciate but it's still not work what bad luck of mine. Now I found one solution is if you can send me whole codeigniter project where some view with links connecting them then I'll download it from github. then I do tick as your answer please if can do it for me it will be big favor thanks

Comment: ok, I'll do later if not solve, probably you are using wrong url `http://localhost/website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/` double check `website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject`  folder name and location

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for your help however many people stuck with this sorts of issue so I just put correct answer through as answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any modification required in my case it's just required to use index.php file in the path so path should be like this http://localhost/website/Codeigniter_Project/MyProject/index.php/welcomelogin/inside

I found this answer through a tutorial which I found while research my answer online link is http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/beginners/creating-controller.html - 
For how to remove **index.php** from the url. Best explain and work for me - [Cannot remove index.php from CodeIgniter URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297770/cannot-remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url)

But thanks anyways who try to help me for my query.:)